# How to deserialized Anchor accounts in Rust

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, anchor-client, idl, deserialization

In JS/TS I can decode an account from bytes using the coder:

```
const program = new Program(IDL, new PublicKey(""), anchorProvider)

const decoded = program.coder.accounts.decode("accountName", buffer)
```

How can I do something similar in a Rust client, assuming I have access to the Anchor IDL?

Answer (score 3):

Anchor will handle this if the struct is from your crate, `pub my_acc: Account<'info, SomeStruct>` will decode for you. If you are using a struct from another crate, you can use:

```
pub fn get_my_struct_from_bytes(v: &[u8]) -> &MyStruct {
    bytemuck::from_bytes(v)
}
```

Note that if it's an Anchor struct, you need to trim the 8-byte discriminator when you the load the account:

```
    /// CHECK: no checks
    #[account()]
    pub my_acc: AccountInfo<'info>,


let some_data = &ctx.accounts.my_acc.try_borrow_data()?[..][8..];
```